# picture format negative numbers

Tags: sas

I try to format the number into billions, millions and thousands as below

```
proc format;
    picture bmk_fmt (round)
        low - 0 = '000,000,000,000)' (prefix='($')
        0 - 1e3 = '000,000,000,000' (prefix='$')
        1e3 - 1e6 = '000,000,000,009K' (mult=1e-3 prefix='$')
        1e6 - 1e9 = '000,000,000,009.9M' (mult=1e-5 prefix='$')
        1e9 - high = '000,000,000,009.9B' (mult=1e-8 prefix='$');
run;
```

However, how can I extend such setting to negative numbers?

E.g `(1.2M)` & `(353K)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide almost all information to solve the problem.
I've just have to use basic math.

Using a `<` sign you can exclude a value from a range e.g. 0 from a negative range.

Here is a final solution.

```
proc format;
    picture bmk_fmt (round default=9)
        low - -1e9 = '009.9B)' (mult=1e-8 prefix='($')
        -1e9 <- -1e6 = '009.9M)' (mult=1e-5 prefix='($')
        -1e6 <- -1e3 = '009.9K)' (mult=1e-2 prefix='($')
        -1e3 <-< 0 = '009.9)' (prefix='($')
        0 -< 1e3 = '009.9' (prefix='$')
        1e3 -< 1e6 = '009.9K' (mult=1e-2 prefix='$')
        1e6 -< 1e9 = '009.9M' (mult=1e-5 prefix='$')
        1e9 - high = '009.9B' (mult=1e-8 prefix='$');
run;
```

Comment: I see. The trick is in the < sign. Without it -1e9 - -1e6 will return error. And the default=9 I guess it's for simplicity ?

Comment: The option `default` means default length of a format. When you use a format you don't have to specify a length e.g. `bmk_fmt.`. It will be the same as `bmk_fmt9.`.